# OUTER JOIN -> want to return something even if empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to return a group_concat on 2 tables
One being my list of schools and the other, some numeric data.

For some dates, i have NO DATA at all in the table SimpleData and so my lEFT OUTER JOINS returns 10 results where i have 11 schools (i need 11 rows for javascript treatment in order too)

here is my query (tell me if i need to give more details about tables

```
 SELECT A.nomEcole, 
    A.Compteur, 
    IFNULL(SUM(B.rendementJour), '0') AS TOTAL, 
    B.jourUS, 
    B.rendementJour
    FROM ecoles A LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleData B ON A.Compteur = B.compteur
   WHERE jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%'
GROUP BY ecole
```

in this example, i have no data in SimpleData for this month( not data was recorded at all)

I have to show either NULL or '0' for this missing school and i'm starting to lose my head on something easy apparently :(

Thanks for any help !

olivier

Comment: remove `WHERE jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%'` and add this into on clause as `LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleData B ON A.Compteur = B.compteur AND B.jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%'`

Comment: i modified as i understand your answer and it still gives me not enough rows (maybe i misunderstood) sorry if that's the case
here is my modified query:

    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(TOTAL) AS liste
    FROM(
    SELECT A.nomEcole, 
 A.Compteur, 
 IFNULL(SUM(B.rendementJour), '0') AS TOTAL, 
 B.jourUS, 
 B.rendementJour
    FROM ecoles A LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleData B ON A.Compteur =         B.compteur AND B.jourUS LIKE '2014-07-%'
    GROUP BY ecole) n

Comment: You should get one record per ecole, as this is what you group by. Do you say there is an ecole you don't get? (And well, your outer query should result in exactly one record, because you aggregate with GROUP_CONCAT without using a GROUP BY.)

Comment: i don't perfectly understand why but this query modified gives me 2 rows where my previous one (first post) gives me 2 rows
i have an additional row with indeed some values at 0 and NULL as i wanted for a school but i should get 11 rows.Why 3 i don't get it ..

    SELECT A.nomEcole, 
        A.Compteur, 
        IFNULL(SUM(B.rendementJour), '0') AS TOTAL, 
        B.jourUS, 
        B.rendementJour
        FROM ecoles A LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleData B ON A.Compteur =  B.compteur AND B.jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%'
    GROUP BY ecole

Answer (score 2):

As one way is mentioned by *@Abhik Chakraborty* where will filter out the records which doesn't match the criteria ,another is you can use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT A.nomEcole, 
A.Compteur, 
SUM(CASE WHEN  jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%' THEN B.rendementJour ELSE 0 END) AS TOTAL, 
B.jourUS, 
B.rendementJour
FROM ecoles A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SimpleData B ON A.Compteur = B.compteur
GROUP BY ecole
```

Comment: That seems to be fully working, thanks M Khalid Junaid !
i will also follow the advices of Gordon Linoff below, as indeed it may very well help me later

Comment: The original statement gave you a random jourUS that is like '2013-07-%', whereas this statement gives you a random jourUS that can be any date. Also this query is likely to be less performant than Gordon's, because you join all records, not only those like '2013-07-%', thus producing a larger intermediate result. It is also less redable, because it does more than you actually want it to do.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i'll modify my query according to Gordon then.
If you say i have risks of random data, i'll get on this right now :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you just need to move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT A.nomEcole, A.Compteur, IFNULL(SUM(B.rendementJour), 0) AS TOTAL, 
       B.jourUS, B.rendementJour
FROM ecoles A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SimpleData B
     ON A.Compteur = B.compteur and b.jourUS >= '2013-07-01' and b.jourUS < '2013-08-01'
GROUP BY A.ecole;
```

Some other changes:

- Don't use single quotes for numeric constants.  Single quotes should really only be used for date and string constants.
- Don't use `like` for dates.  `like` is an operation on strings, not dates, and the date has to be implicitly converted to a string.  Instead, do direct comparisons on the date ranges you are interested in.
- I would also recommend that the table aliases be abbreviations for the tables you are using.  This makes the query easier to read.  (So `e` instead of `A` for `ecoles`.)

Also note that the values that you are returning for `JourUS` and `RendementJour` are indeterminate.  If there are multiple rows in the `B` table that match, then an arbitrary value will be returned.  Perhaps you want `max()` or `group_concat()` for them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, 
i 'll follow your advices for the quotes and naming.
At first using direct date comparison as you suggest is not easy as the date are stored as Varchar (would work too? maybe convert them is the way to go)

Thanks for your answer , i'll check if i can alter my php code to reflect that. I try to stay as close as a clean code can be so i'll do that if i have to.

thanks ;)

Comment: @olivierL . . . You should store dates in the database using the date/time data types.  `like` is appropriate if the value is stored as a string.

Comment: i'll go your way as advised by @M Khalid Junaid below , i'll just have to tweak some more codes to get the comparison dates for the query to work.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause turns the LEFT OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN, because outer-joined records values are NULL and NULL is never LIKE '2013-07-%'.

This is the reason you must move `jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%'` to the ON clause, because you only want to join records where jourUS LIKE '2013-07-%' and otherwise outer join a null record.